# Improve performance of python script to filter unpaired reads in a pair of FASTQ files

Tags: python, oop, fastq, sequencing

I have some paired end sequencing data. However, the files are not properly paired. There are unpaired reads which need to be removed to make the read pair files consistent. Though there are solutions like using Trimmomatic. I want suggestions as to how I can improve the performance of my own script. The current version processes at about 10K records per second.

```
import sys


class FastqRecord(object):
    def __init__(self, block, unique_col=1, unique_type=int, sep=' '):
        self.block = "".join(block[:])
        self.header = block[0][1:].rstrip('\n')
        self.uid = unique_type(self.header.split(sep)[unique_col])

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.uid == other.uid

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.uid > other.uid

class Fastq(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.file = filename
        self.handle = open(self.file)
        self.count = 0
        self.record = self.next()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return FastqRecord([self.handle.next(), self.handle.next(), self.handle.next(), self.handle.next()])

    def update(self):
        try:
            self.record = self.next()
            self.count+=1
        except StopIteration:
            self.record = False
            self.handle.close()

def fn_from_path(path):
    return path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]

def flush_handle(obj, handle):
    handle.write(obj.record.block)
    for x in obj:
        handle.write(x.block)
    return True

@profile
def main():
    file1, file2, out_dir = (sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3].rstrip('/'))
    #file1, file2, out_dir = ('./test/SRR2130002_1.fastq', './test/SRR2130002_2.fastq', '.')
    out_handles = {
        'p1': open('%s/%s.fastq' % (out_dir, fn_from_path(file1)), 'w'),
        'p2': open('%s/%s.fastq' % (out_dir, fn_from_path(file2)), 'w'),
        's': open('%s/%s_unpaired.fastq' % (out_dir, fn_from_path(file1).split('_')[0]), 'w')
    }
    f1, f2 = Fastq(file1), Fastq(file2)
    while True:
        print "\r%9d %9d %9d" % (f1.count, f2.count, f1.count-f2.count),
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if f1.record is False or f2.record is False:
            if f1.record is False:
                flush_handle(f2, out_handles['s'])
            else:
                flush_handle(f1, out_handles['s'])
            break
        if f1.record == f2.record:
            out_handles['p1'].write(f1.record.block)
            out_handles['p2'].write(f2.record.block)
            f1.update()
            f2.update()
        elif f1.record > f2.record:
            out_handles['s'].write(f2.record.block)
            f2.update()
        else:
            out_handles['s'].write(f1.record.block)
            f1.update()
    for i in out_handles:
        out_handles[i].close()
    print "\n Done!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is how my FASTQ files look:

```
head SRR2130002_1.fasta

@SRR2130002.1 1 length=39
CCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCAAAGACAGGCAA
+SRR2130002.1 1 length=39
AAAAA7F<<FF<F.<FFFFF77F.))))FA.))))))7A
@SRR2130002.2 2 length=39
TTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTATCTCGTA
+SRR2130002.2 2 length=39
<AAAAAA.7FFFFFFFFFF.<...).A.F7F7)A.FAA<
@SRR2130002.3 3 length=39
CTACCCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACAAAACCCCAAAACAAA
```

Thanks

UPDATE:
I ran a line profiler (kernprof) on the main() function. And got following stats:

Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.808629 s
File: paired_extractor.py
Function: main at line 46

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    46                                           @profile
    47                                           def main():
    48         1            4      4.0      0.0      file1, file2, out_dir = (sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3].rstrip('/'))
    49                                               #file1, file2, out_dir = ('./test/SRR2130002_1.fastq', './test/SRR2130002_2.fastq', '.')
    50         1            1      1.0      0.0      out_handles = {
    51         1         4830   4830.0      0.6          'p1': open('%s/%s.fastq' % (out_dir, fn_from_path(file1)), 'w'),
    52         1         4118   4118.0      0.5          'p2': open('%s/%s.fastq' % (out_dir, fn_from_path(file2)), 'w'),
    53         1         1283   1283.0      0.2          's': open('%s/%s_unpaired.fastq' % (out_dir, fn_from_path(file1).split('_')[0]), 'w')
    54                                               }
    55         1         2945   2945.0      0.4      f1, f2 = Fastq(file1), Fastq(file2)
    56     25001        23354      0.9      2.9      while True:
    57     25001       105393      4.2     13.0          print "\r%9d %9d %9d" % (f1.count, f2.count, f1.count-f2.count),
    58     25001        68264      2.7      8.4          sys.stdout.flush()
    59     25001        29858      1.2      3.7          if f1.record is False or f2.record is False:
    60         1            1      1.0      0.0              if f1.record is False:
    61         1         9578   9578.0      1.2                  flush_handle(f2, out_handles['s'])
    62                                                       else:
    63                                                           flush_handle(f1, out_handles['s'])
    64         1            1      1.0      0.0              break
    65     25000        47062      1.9      5.8          if f1.record == f2.record:
    66     23593        41546      1.8      5.1              out_handles['p1'].write(f1.record.block)
    67     23593        34040      1.4      4.2              out_handles['p2'].write(f2.record.block)
    68     23593       216319      9.2     26.8              f1.update()
    69     23593       196077      8.3     24.2              f2.update()
    70      1407         2340      1.7      0.3          elif f1.record > f2.record:
    71                                                       out_handles['s'].write(f2.record.block)
    72                                                       f2.update()
    73                                                   else:
    74      1407         2341      1.7      0.3              out_handles['s'].write(f1.record.block)
    75      1407        13231      9.4      1.6              f1.update()
    76         4            9      2.2      0.0      for i in out_handles:
    77         3         6023   2007.7      0.7          out_handles[i].close()
    78         1           11     11.0      0.0      print "\n Done!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me caveat my response with the fact that it's typically hard/impossible to optimize code without doing due-diligence with a profiler (which is what I'm about to do, since I don't have your fasta files). You also seem to have some good habits with strings (like using `join`). It looks like you don't need

```
print "\r%9d %9d %9d" % (f1.count, f2.count, f1.count-f2.count),
sys.stdout.flush()
```

as this is just outputting stats to console. You'll get a little speedup by removing that...but nothing major jumped out at me.

Just as a matter of personal opinion, if you want general processing speed, I'd suggest using C/C++. They don't have the overhead of the interpreter. The Python interpreter is an amazing tool, but it wasn't built for speed. It was built for correctness/security/ease-of-use. Specifically for string manipulations, Perl is king from what I hear, although admittedly I've only written 10s of lines of Perl in my life.

Comment: I ran line profiler on the code. Please see the UPDATED section of the question above. It seems the bottleneck is I/O. Half the time is lost in getting a block of next four lines. Is there any way I can prefetch lines. Should I use separate thread for that?

Comment: So you spend 13% of time on printing (you don't **need** to print). So removing that print/flush statement will give you about a 20% speedup!

Comment: I/O is typically a bottle neck, I don't think there's much you can do here (except for upgrading hardware and maybe trying to buffer more before you write). I don't know if buffering more would even give you a speed improvement, you'd have to test it. There's a tradeoff with having a ton of crap on the heap/stack vs. not writing to files as often.